# Waiting for MongoDB findOne callback to complete before finishing app.get()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, express, callback

I'm relatively new to Javascript and I am having trouble understanding how to use a MongoDB callback with an ExpressJS get.  My problem seems to be if it takes too long for the database search, the process falls out of the app.get() and gives the webpage an "Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Currently it works with most values, either finding the value or properly returning a 404 - not found, but there are some cases where it hangs for a few seconds before turning the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.  In the debugger, it reaches the end of the app.get(), where it returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, and after that the findOne callback finishes and goes to the 404, but by then it is too late.

I've tried using async and introducing waits with no success, which makes me feel like I am using app.get and findOne incorrectly.

Here is a general version of my code below:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    var value = null;
    if (req.query.param)
        value = req.query.param;
    else
        value = defaultValue;

    var query = {start: {$lte: value}, end: {$gte: value}};
    var data = collection.findOne(query, function (err, data) {
        if (err){
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        else if (data) {
            res.end(data);
        }
        else{
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });     
});
```

What can I do to have the response wait for the database search to complete?  Or is there a better way to return a database document from a request?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No it's not, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you try calling `res.send(data)` or `res.json(data)` instead of using `res.end`?  That's the more typical way to return data in a response.

Comment: Same result.  When I get an Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, it presents that error before it goes into the callback function of findOne.

Answer (score 0):

You should measure how long the db query takes.

If it's slow >5sec and you can't speed it up, than it might be a good idea to decouple it from the request by using some kind of job framework.

Return a redirect the url where the job status/result will be available.

Comment: Is this the only way to "wait" for the db query?  Would there be any guarantee that the new page would have the data?

Comment: If there is some kind of hard connection timeout (by client, server or proxy) then this might be the only way.

Comment: Have you measured (logged) how long the queries take? Maybe there's a completely different problem (browser issue, firewall, router, ...).

Comment: The connection seems to get closed after around 3 seconds.  Queries typically take ~20ms (if it is in the DB).  Some queries searching for values not in the database take 4-5 seconds, resulting iin the connection closing before it properly returns a 404.  I've also witnessed good queries taking 4-5 seconds resulting in the same problem if the network is slow.

Comment: 4-5 seconds is a range where timeouts can occur. So you have 2 options: A) ensure the query is fast (add index, make sure indexes fit in RAM, use hint, etc...) B) use a job fw as described in the answer.

Comment: It depends on your setup. If you only have one worker than [async#queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) might be sufficient. Otherwise, you should use something like [Kue](http://learnboost.github.io/kue/)

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly about this, but I completely ignored the fact that when using http.createServer(), I had a timeout set of 3000 ms.  I misunderstood what this timeout was for and this is what was causing my connection to close prematurely.  Increasing this number allowed my most stubborn queries to complete.